# How to use elasticsearch in angular to highlight search query for livechat feature

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticSearch for LiveChat feature that contains conversations and messages collections. And I want to search a message or participant name in the conversation using elasticsearch (multi collection search in two object model conversation and message), giving me as result the message highlighted and redirecting me to the message position in the conversation like in Facebook search engine in messenger.
I am using .Net core in the backend and angular in the frontend

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What did you do? Can you provide your specific code?